# How to find location of multiple touches in Cocos2d 3.2?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I want to get the location of two fingers taped in view in CGPoint.

How can i get that from CCTouchEvent?

i have tried so far:

```
-(void)touchMoved:(CCTouch *)touch withEvent:(CCTouchEvent *)event{

    if ([[event allTouches] count]==2) {

       NSLog(@"Detected");
       NSLog(@"event: %@",event.allTouches);

    }

}
```

Comment: CGPoint location = event.allTouches[0].locationInWorld

Comment: see this reference http://cocos2d.spritebuilder.com/docs/api/Classes/CCTouch.html

Comment: @AlexanderTkachenko this does not work... alltouches is NSMutableDictionary not an array,

Comment: so enumerate values of dictionary if it's dictionary

Comment: CGPoint location = event.allTouches.allValues.[0].locationInWorld

Comment: this works for me.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By enumerating the values of allTouches:

```
-(void)touchMoved:(CCTouch *)touch withEvent:(CCTouchEvent *)event{

if ([[event allTouches] count]==2) {


    CGPoint fingerOne = [event.allTouches.allValues[0] locationInWorld];
    CGPoint fingerTwo = [event.allTouches.allValues[1] locationInWorld];

    NSLog(@"fingerOne: x = %f, y = %f",fingerOne.x,fingerOne.y);
    NSLog(@"fingerTwo: x = %f, y = %f",fingerTwo.x,fingerTwo.y);


 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you need to try this:
the first param is not a CCTouch anymore it needs to be a set so

```
-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(CCTouchEvent *)event{
    for(CCTouch* touch in touches){
        [touch getLocation];
    }
}
```